# How to fix Wordpress "Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: " errors?

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, warnings, preg-match-all

I've been struggling with this new wordpress website for a while now. I use a theme which I always use to make websites, but this time I get a lot of errors regarding the "*warning: `preg_match_all()`: Compilation failed:*".

Everything seems to work fine, but after updating a page I get redirected to a screen saying:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 11 in /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_salient/include/autoload/hook-vc-grid.php on line 163
>
> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 11 in /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_salient/include/autoload/hook-vc-grid.php on line 163
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_salient/include/autoload/hook-vc-grid.php:163) in /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-admin/post.php on line 222
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_salient/include/autoload/hook-vc-grid.php:163) in /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1251
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_salient/include/autoload/hook-vc-grid.php:163) in /customers/b/5/2/tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/httpd.www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1254

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Code of my homepage:
[view-source:https://www.tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/](http://view-source:https://www.tati-vastgoedstyling.nl/)

Comment: That's fine, but, where is your code?

Comment: How is this related to Composer?

Comment: @Toto How could I share this with you? website is www.tati-vastgoedstyling.nl

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55120204/edit) and add relevant code, especially the updated part.

Comment: @Toto Changed the question. Might want to help me out with the code part. Where can I find this code? I'm not a professional at this topic.

Comment: You said you have a problem after updating a page. Show us the modified page, without it, it's impossible to say what is wrong.

Comment: @Toto aah thanks, I think I misunderstood. It's not actually a problem specific to one page. Everytime I try to update a page or anything whatsoever on my website I get redirected to the blank page with the errors as stated above.

Will share code of the homepage in my first comment.

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this? I am getting this same error.